# How to format a partition for bootcamp without to partitioning all drive?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, bootcamp, partition

I'm trying to install a Windows 10 in my MacBook Pro 2012 with El Capitan. I am now in the step that Bootcamp will create a volume for Windows installation. My MacBook got two internal (physical) disk drives:

- One main SATA SSD 240GB with the OS X, and I wish to keep like this.
- One secondary SATA HDD 500GB (the original HDD) in the optical drive bay using a HDD Caddy.

The second HDD got a 240GB that Carbon Copy was using to daily backup, now I'm using an external HDD so I'll use this space to Windows. The rest of HDD is an OS X volume for everything that does not fit inside the SSD (extra space).

So diskutil reports this info:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *240.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS MacProSSDBoot           239.7 GB   disk0s2
/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS WindowsBoot             239.5 GB   disk1s2
   3:                  Apple_HFS MacProHDPlus            259.6 GB   disk1s4
/dev/disk3 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *8.0 GB     disk3
   1:                 DOS_FAT_32 WININSTALL              8.0 GB     disk3s1
/dev/disk4 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            J_CCSA_X64FRE_PT-BR... +4.4 GB     disk4
/dev/disk5 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            Boot Camp              +2.8 GB     disk5
```

The problem is Bootcamp is showing two drives - SDD and HDD - and my options are to divide the SDD (don't want to) or to format all 500GB HDD to make it exclusive for Windows. I don't want to dedicate all that space for Windows! Maybe if I do format the HDD again but I'll have to find some place to save all the - and it takes some time. Also, I am afraid of to do as Bootcamp said (format all 500GB) and not being able to resize the Windows partition to recreate the OS X partition.

Is there "on the fly" solution without removing the OS X partition? Can I do as Bootcamp says and resize to decrease partition size so I can bring my data back?

Comment: I assume at this point the Boot Camp Assistance has put files on a USB flash drive?

Comment: Yes, I did the two first steps already.